What are some good introductory economics books for the actuarial science formation examination in economics and law by the DAV
The DAV has one examination about economics and law within their six principle examinations during their formation in actuarial science, as you can see on this page. What are some good introductory economics books which prepare for this examination among other things. Concerning the contents covered, this pdf gives a clue.
If the book or books (if there are several for each bullet point in the list in the pdf) go beyond what is usually asked in an introductory examination on this topic, it is fine.
I read both English and German; the language doesn't matter. I have a PhD in Mathematics and a good grasp of probability theory and statistics. So, the prerequisites in this regard, can (but must not be) rather high.
(I am aware that not all topics in the linked pdf are necessarily economical. If it matters for your answer, you can restrict yourself to some of the bullets with book recommendations which you feel are adequate for this site and fit your background.)
